# Why does the -1 th index is always 0 in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std

Can someone say why does this code prints 0 ? I thought it would be showing some exceptions.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(8);
    cout << v[-1];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Why does the -1 th index is always 0 in a vector?

It is not. The behaivour of the program is undefined.

> I thought it would be showing some exceptions.

Your expectation is misguided. `std:vector::operator[]` is not guaranteed to throw an exception when the index is out of bounds.

`std:vector::at` does behave as you would expect.

Comment: It should be noted that the MSVC standard library have an extension that throws out of bounds exceptions even for `operator[]`, at least in debug builds.